# Using assignment as a condition expression?

Tags: c++, c, if-statement, assignment-operator, evaluation

Consider:

```
if (a=5) {
   /* do something */
}
```

How does the assignment work as a condition?

Is it based on non-zero value of l-value?

Comment: Are you compiling in C++ or C?

Comment: `int war = false; if(war = true) { launchnuke(); }`

Comment: @WTP: Never compare a boolean to anything. A boolean is already boolean: `if (war) launchnuke();` And programmers who assigns `true` or `false` to a non-boolean deserves all kinds of meyham launched against them.

Comment: @David: Where did WTP compare a boolean to a boolean?

Comment: @Tomalak: He didn't, but `if(var = true)` was probably intended to be `if(var == true)`.  Writing it as `if (var)` in the first place would have neatly avoided the potential `=` vs. `==`' confusion.

Comment: @Keith: Given the subject matter, I'm fairly certain that he was being ironic.

Comment: @George: Accept answers to your questions, please.

Comment: @WTP That made my day :-)

Answer (score 30):

#### C++ — ISO/IEC 14882:2003(E)

> `[5.17/1]` There are several assignment operators, all of which group
>   right-to-left. All require a modifiable lvalue as their left operand,
>   and the type of an assignment expression is that of its left operand.
>   **The result of the assignment operation is the value stored in the left
>   operand after the assignment has taken place**; the result is an lvalue.

The result of the expression `a = 5` is `5`.

> `[6.4/4]` [..] The value of a *condition* that is an expression is the value of the
>   expression, **implicitly converted to `bool`** for statements other than
>   `switch`. [..]

A conversion to `bool` takes place.

> `[4.12/1]` An rvalue of arithmetic, enumeration, pointer, or pointer to member
>   type can be converted to an rvalue of type `bool`. A zero value, null
>   pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted to `false`; **any
>   other value is converted to `true`.**

`5` converts to boolean `true`.

> `[6.4.1/1]` **If the condition (6.4) yields true the first
>   substatement is executed.** [..]

`true` is treated as an `if` statement success.

---

#### C — ISO/IEC 9899:1999(E)

> `[6.5.16/3]` An assignment operator stores a value in the object
>   designated by the left operand. **An assignment expression has the value
>   of the left operand after the assignment**, but is not an lvalue. [..]

The result of the expression `a = 5` is `5`.

> `[6.8.4.1/2]` In both forms, **the first substatement is executed if the
>   expression compares unequal to 0**. [..]

`5` is treated as an `if` statement success.

---

### General

Code like this is almost always a mistake; the author likely intended `if (a == 5) {}`. However, sometimes it is deliberate. You may see code like this:

```
if (x = foo()) {
   cout << "I set x to the result of foo(), which is truthy";
   // ... stuff
}
```

Comment: To make sure it's no mistake you can write `if ((a=5) != 0)` which is semantically the same as `if (a=5)`.

Comment: Will `0.0` be considered as zero value?

Comment: @Stan: Looks like zero to me! (Though recall that floating-point is inaccurate.)

Comment: Since the question is tagged both C and C++ it might be nice to mention you're citing C++, not C. The reasoning is rather different for the two.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: Fonts could be a little smaller.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: Naah, The answer is very good, but those **BIG** heading fonts really hurt the eyes :)

Answer (score 1):

`if(a=x)` is equivalent to `if(x)` in addition to `a` assigned with `x`. So if the expression `x` evaluates to a non-zero value, then `if(x)`  simply becomes `if(true)`. Otherwise, it becomes `if(false)`.

In your case, since `x = 5`, that means `f(a=5)` is equivalent to `if(true)` in addition to `a` assigned with `5`.

Comment: This is a bit misleading: `if(a=5)` is not equivalent to `if(true)` because it also assigns `a`.

Comment: -1: `if (a = x)' and `if (x)' are not equivalent, the first expression has a side-effect.

Comment: @interjay: I just edited this, when you both were commenting.

Answer (score 1):

Every non-zero value will be considered as **true**.

So some people will suggest you write

```
5 == a
```

to avoid that you make mistake **==** by **=**.

Comment: Most compilers will warn about that mistake nowadays.

Comment: @Bo Persson: surely it is. But some lazy people would like to turn off the warning, so let's make it an error than a warning.

Comment: -1: To me this is ugly and does not provide a general solution.

Comment: I don't suggest writing `5 == a`. I suggest writing `a == 5`. :) Just do it; it's not hard. And if you're turning off warnings then you deserve everything you get.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: well I agree with you. So I said 'some people' but not just 'I'. Of course '5==a' is ugly, however, _some people_ (e.g. my boss) assists that... sometimes you have to surrender.

Comment: In my opinion, the construct `if (5 ==a) {...}` is ugly, ugly, ugly, and it is useless against mistakes such as `if (i = j) {...}`. BTW, I did not downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is based on the zero/non-zero value which a is assigned. To some people (myself included) it is also considered bad practice to have expressions with side-effects in your code, so the mentioned code fragment would preferably be written as something like

```
a = 5;
...
if (a != 0) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: i think it's fine if it's if (int a=foo()) { ... }   ... if-scoped assignment.

Answer (score 0):

In more modern usage, you may sometimes see this pattern used to handle `optional`s:

```cpp
std::optional x = ...;
if (auto v = x) {
  // Block only executes if x contained a value, accessible as *v
}
```