# Operator precedence in C++

Tags: c++

For the following function

> ```
> int search(int n) {
>     return arr[n] == n ? n : arr[n] = search(arr[n]);
> }
> ```

Not very sure exactly what it's supposed to do. According to what I understand about operator precedence, my guess is that above is equivalent to

```cpp
int search(int n) {
    if (arr[n] == n) {
        return n;
    } else {
        return arr[n] = search(arr[n]);
    }
}
```

but then it doesn't really make sense to me that the function is returning an assignment? Or am I interpreting it wrong entirely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your expansion of the expression looks correct to me.

I think what you're missing is that assignment expressions can be evaluated as a value. The value returned is the value of the left operand after assignment.

So `arr[n] = search(arr[n])` effectively returns `arr[n]` after it was assigned the return value of `search(arr[n])`.

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6807398/9516968) covers the part of the standard that allows this and answers a similar question.

---

After testing some different initial arrays and arguments with that function, I should warn you that it can throw a StackOverflow exception!
For Example: `arr[2] = {1,0};` and `search(1);`.

Comment: My interpretation was incorrect. I deleted my answer.

Comment: Actually `arr` is created via `for (int i = 1; i <= d; ++i) arr[i] = i` somewhere else in the code so there wouldn't be a case of endless recursion

Comment: Okay further down the code I see `arr[search(a)] = search(b)` so I'm not so sure now...