# Assignment in an 'if' statement. How is the output correct?

Tags: c++, c, if-statement, syntax, conditional-statements

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVy9V.png) in case if the image not is visible.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fun(int n)
{
    if(n=4)
        return n;
    else
        return 2*fun(n+1);
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d", fun(2));
}
```

This is the code snippet and the output is given as 4 by the professor.

How is the output correct?

Is it possible that n=4 is assigned in the 'if-else' statement as the assignment operator is correct, but the "if" condition will not work as the syntax is wrong and the output will be directly given as 4.

Comment: All major compilers should give a warning here.

Comment: Related: *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way***, *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer **is** correct, and there aren't any syntax errors.

`=` is an assignment operator, and in C/C++, `(n = 4)` is a valid expression that evaluates to true as long as the expression is not `(n = 0)`, because n will then be considered as `false` by C. Note that in C/C++, `0` is `false` and everything else is `true`.

Hence, `if (n = 4)` is perfectly valid and always evaluates to true. Of course, in the process, there will also be an assignment involved.

Thus, what happens in the code above is that

1. the integer `n` is assigned the value 4 in `n = 4`
2. `(n=4)` as an expression returns true.
3. return n (4).

So the answer is 4.

Comment: I understood it now...Thanks a lot for the explanation.

Comment: More accurately, the assignment operator returns the value of the left-hand operator (in this case, 4), which is implicitly converted to true by the if statement. The expression (n=4) evaluates to 4.

Answer (score 1):

Assignment in a *if-else* statement is valid syntax and the branching will depend on the value of n.

Example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int n = 2;

    if (n = 0) {
        std::cout << "Never printed\n";
    }

    if (n = 4) {
        std::cout << "Always printed\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Compiler explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/fEYPcq

Comment: I understood it now...Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: It is valid syntax, but it is best avoided (it is often a [premature optimisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize) (and a source of error), and compilers will probably figure it out anyway).

Answer (score 0):

> "Is it possible that `n = 4` is assigned in the `if-else` statement as the assignment operator is correct, but the `if` condition will not work as the syntax is wrong....?"

The syntax is not wrong and the `if` condition does work. It is perfectly valid. And yes, the assignment is also valid/correct.

With `if (n = 4)` you assign the value of `4` to the function-local variable `n`, although this makes less sense since `n` is a parameter and is meant to be feed with different values at each call to the function `fun()`.

But I guess the intention of your professor is exactly to demonstrate this trickery, so it makes sense.

So the value of `n` is not `2` anymore; It is `4`.

---

This is a valid expression for the `if` condition and evaluates to `1`/`true` since the value/expression to be assigned is or does not evaluate not `0`.

Usually a compiler will warn you about doing so nonetheless to avoid any undesired result here by suggesting optional parentheses around the assignment like: `if ((n = 4))`.

Clang:

> *warning: using the result of an assignment as a condition without parentheses [-Wparentheses]*

GCC:

> *warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]*

If you explicitly want to remove these warnings, use the `-Wno-parentheses` flag. But it is recommended not to do so.

---

Since the `if` condition is `true`, it doesn't get to the recursive part in the `else` condition and the function `fun` immediately returns `n` which is `4`.

So is the return value of `4` displayed by the call to `printf()` in the caller.

---

My favorite to remember that is this:

```
int war = false;
if (war = true) { launch nuke; }
```

[Credits go to WTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807393/using-assignment-as-a-condition-expression#comment8083835_6807393).

Maybe you'll catch the joke. ;-)

Comment: launch nukes...lol...ya i get it now thanks for the awesome explanation

Answer (score 0):

You should use `==` operator to make a confront between two compatible values.
`if(n = 4)` assign 4 to n and then the if statement is always true. So the return value will always be 4.

Comment: Re *"make a confront"*: [machine translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_translation)?