# Can you compare an assignment of a variable to NULL?

Tags: c++

I'm working with some code that have variable assignment and null checking on the same line. As an example: `while((var1 = func1()) != NULL) { doStuff(); }` My question is, is the check comparing the value of var1 to NULL, or the process of assigning a variable to NULL? I'm not sure that makes sense, but the code seems to get stuck in a loop despite the fact that func1() returns a null value.

Comment: It's doing both

Comment: How do you mean?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using assignment as a condition expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807393/using-assignment-as-a-condition-expression)

Comment: Maybe. If func1() returns null, then the expression var1 = func1() would evaluate to false, which is equivalent to null? The loop would exit in that case.

Comment: It's doing neither, it's comparing the result of the expression to NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment

For all built-in types, the assignment operator will return the assigned value. So, it does

```
var1 = func1();
```

then it checks `var1 != NULL` for the condition.

Comment: That makes sense. If that's the case, then something else is causing the behaviour I'm seeing, but this answers my question. Thanks.